# Microsoft.Owin.Security Google Challenge only working with ReturnUrl

Tags: .net, vb.net, katana

I am having a strange problem in my Google auth implementation.  I have a vb.net web forms app that is utilizing Microsoft.Owin.Security to handle Google Authentication.  The process works fine, but only when there is a ReturnUrl in the browser login page.  Right now I am redirecting if the system can't find a match by email.  If I redirect without a ReturnUrl the next attempt doesn't work.  I'm not sure why this is only working with this query parameter.

Working URL: http://local.template.com/Security/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSecurity%2fLogin.aspx

None working URL: http://local.template.com/Security/Login.aspx#

Startup Class:

```
Imports Owin
Imports Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
Imports Microsoft.Owin
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google
<Assembly: OwinStartup(GetType(Startup))>
Partial Public Class Startup
    ' For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301883
    Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
        ' Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)

        Dim googleOptions = New GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() With {
            .ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Google.ClientID"),
            .ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Google.Secret")
            }
          googleOptions.Provider = New GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationProvider() 

        googleOptions.Scope.Add("openid")
        googleOptions.Scope.Add("profile")
        googleOptions.Scope.Add("email")

        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleOptions)


    End Sub

End Class
```

Login Click:

```
Public Sub btnGoogle_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) 

        Dim provider = "Google"
        ' Request a redirect to the external login provider
        Dim redirectUrl As String = ResolveUrl([String].Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}&provider={1}", RedirectPageUrl,provider))

        Dim properties As AuthenticationProperties = New AuthenticationProperties() With {.RedirectUri = redirectUrl}

        Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(properties, provider)
        Response.StatusCode = 401
        Response.[End]()

End Sub
```

Failure to match Redirect:

```
    ''' <summary>
    '''     Signs out the external cookie and redirects
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub SignOutExternalAuthAndRedirect(Optional ByVal userNotFound As Boolean = False,
                                               Optional ByVal signedInEmailAddress As String = "")
        Dim authManager = Context.GetOwinContext().Authentication
        authManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)
        Dim errormessage = "Something went wrong while trying to sign in with Google"
        If userNotFound Then _
            errormessage = "Invalid login. There is no user account associated with email address " &
                           signedInEmailAddress
        JGrowl.ShowMessage(JGrowlMessageType.Error, errormessage, isDelayed := True)
        RedirectOnFail()
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    '''     redirect to login page or default page if signedin
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub RedirectOnFail()

        Response.Redirect("~/Security/Login.aspx")

    End Sub
```